# NSMutableArray getting freed on iPad but not in Simulator

Tags: ios, ipad, ios-simulator, automatic-ref-counting

I have the following code in .m code

```
@implementation MyGameController
{
    NSMutableArray* viewsarray;
}
```

I am initializing it this way

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   viewsarray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
   for (int i=0; i < TOTAL_ITEMS; i++)
   {
        ItemController* iv = [[ItemController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ItemPadXib" bundle:nil];

        [viewsarray addObject:iv];
    }
}
```

When I check at the end of this function - the array is intact and contains all my items. However, later it gets freed ( I think ) and viewsarray is set to nil.

I know this since later i try to access it like this

```
- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
    ItemController* iv1 = [viewsarray objectAtIndex:index];
    ....
}
```

When i set a `bp` in this function - the `viewsarray` is `nil`

I tried to declare the `viewsarray` as a `property` but the behavior is the same

One important thing - on Simulator it works just fine. What is different ? Is ARC behaving differently ?

Comment: Try deriving your own class from NSMutableArray and see when dealloc is getting called in this derived class.

Comment: thank ESoft. Will try it right now

Comment: It's difficult to derive from `NSMutableArray` (`NSArray` is a class cluster). It might be easier to set an associated object and observe its destruction.

Answer (score 2):

The `viewsarray` instance variable is strong (by default) and so cannot be released automatically. Memory management (by ARC) is identical in the simulator and on the device. Your bug is elsewhere.

Comment: @LouisShraga No, it's an answer to your question "Is ARC behaving differently?".

Comment: cmon, obviously my question is not about ARC but about my bug. "Is ARC behaving differently" is a thought, an idea. "What is different" is the question. If I just wanted to know if ARC behaves different on device I would have a short question asking just that... And that would not even be a valid question on SO... Some common sense, please

Comment: In your question is no hint to a possible reason for your bug. That's what I tried to make clear with my answer.